PowerApps set combobox to auto populate username
I have a sharepoint list and one of the columns is a user column where the user has to use the dropdown, search and select their name. In the PowerApps when they create a new form they must do the same, but how can I make the combobox autopopulate their name (based on who ever is logged in and making the request)?
Thanks!

You can follow the following steps:

First you need to setup Items property of your dropdown. This will give to option to chose as of your SharePoint:
Choices(<SharePoint List Nam>.<Column Name>)


While saving you need to save it like this:
Patch(
 <SharePoint List Name>,
 Defaults(<SharePoint List Name>),
 {
     <Column Name>: dropdown.Selected
 }
)



In case if you want the dropdown to select the logged in user, then put Office365Users.MyProfileV2() on DefaultSelected property.
